# "rails 4.1 +" の範囲

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ドキュメントを読んでいたら、’Rails 4.1+’以上はこれこれしてくださいと書いてありましたが、これの指定している範囲はどこからどこまでなのでしょうか。
 Rails 4.2も含まれるのでしょうか。
 Rails 5も含まれますか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 英語圏で良くみかける表現に「XXX バージョン 1.0 以降」の意味で「XXX version 1.0+」のように'+'で表記されることがあります。そういう一般論の話でしょうか？

Comment: はい。そうです。ということは、rails 5とかも入りますか？

Comment: 字義通り解釈すれば、Rails 4.1以降の全てのバージョンを含むと思います。（とはいえ、将来に渡って常に完全互換を保証するなんてことは無いでしょうけど。）

Comment: ありがとうございます！助かりました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

英語圏で良くみかける表現として、「XXX バージョン1.0 以降」の意味で「XXX version 1.0+」のように'+'を使って表記されることがあります。

ですから字義通り解釈すると、Rails 4.1 以降の全てのバージョンを指しています。

<del>（とはいえ、将来に渡って常に完全互換を保証するなんてことは無いでしょうけど。）</del>

---

[@sanadanさんコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9507/#comment8646_9512) をうけて追記：

RubyGemsのバージョニング方針では、[Semantic Versioning](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#semantic-versioning)を採用しているそうです。あわせて参考にしてください。

> Semantic versioning boils down to:
>
> - **PATCH 0.0.x** level changes for implementation level detail changes, such as small bug fixes
> - **MINOR 0.x.0** level changes for any backwards compatible API changes, such as new functionality/features
> - **MAJOR x.0.0** level changes for backwards *incompatible* API changes, such as changes that will break existing users code if they update

Comment: 私は4.1以上5未満と解釈しています。というのも、gemのメジャーバージョンでは互換が失われる場合に増えるのが推奨（[参照](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#semantic-versioning)）となっているので、5では通用しない可能性が高いからです。

Comment: なるほど。バージョニングの方針はプロジェクトにより様々ですね。